# Why wouldn't the default Control Adapter mappings work on Chrome or Safari?

Tags: asp.net, browser-detection, control-adapter

I have confirmed that my Control Adapters are not triggering in Chrome and Safari.  I've debugged, and the breakpoints inside the adapters just don't get hit in Chrome/Safari, when they work perfectly find in Firefox/IE.  So, for Chrome/Safari, IIS is just ignoring the mapping.

My AdapterMappings.browser file looks like this:

```
<browsers>
  <browser refID="Default">
    <controlAdapters>
      [...adapters here....]
    </controlAdapters>
   </browser>
</browsers>
```

This should provide mappings for all browsers, correct?

I used the Charles proxy to check what user agents were being sent.  They are:

```
Mozilla/5.0 (Windows; U; Windows NT 5.1; en-US) AppleWebKit/532.5 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/4.1.249.1064 Safari/532.5

Mozilla/5.0 (Windows; U; Windows NT 5.1; en-US) AppleWebKit/531.22.7 (KHTML, like Gecko) Version/4.0.5 Safari/531.22.7
```

Any idea why this would be?  Everything I've read tells me that my browser mappings are correct?  And, as I said this works for IE/Firefox, so I know my configuration is technically correct.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We found the problem.  It was errant code that specifically disabling the adapters in Chrome/Safari.  They work fine, normally.